# How to ignore header in text file when reading it

Tags: arrays, swift, macos

I am trying to read a text file and store the data inside into structs and I am interested in finding out how to ignore the first 4 lines (text header) in the text file.

This is the text file:

```
text file
```

I am only going to need the numeric values from it (year int, month int, max double, etc.) and ignore the four text lines above them.

This is the code I use to store the values as a collection of structs:

```
code
```

Comment: Note that your program will crash if any line has less than 7 entries, or if any of the entries is not a valid number. You might want to code more defensively ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`func dropFirst(_ n: Int)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688675-dropfirst) to skip initial lines:

```
let lines = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
for line in lines.dropFirst(4) {
    // ...
}
```

`dropFirst(4)` returns an “array slice” with all but the first 4
elements in the `lines` array, which means that the element storage
is not duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

If it's always 4 lines then @Martin R has a good answer, otherwise you could see if the first word can be converted to an int like

```
for line in filtered {

  let x = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
  guard let year = Int(x[0] else {
    continue
  }
  ....
```